# Internet Explorer error - ... This content cannot be displayed in a frame

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe

I maintain a job board where users have the ability to insert url based job ads (they post a link and their job ad page is displayed on our system). Everything works fine on Chrome, but Internet Explorer and FF just refuses to show the page.

FF shows a blank page and IE Error looks like this:

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame
>         To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be
>   displayed in a frame.   What you can try:    Open this content in a
>   new window

As I understand their website is set no to be shown on an iFrame and I already contacted them about this. But here's the question.. why is Chrome displaying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is noone's man land!  if you noticed, google forces SSL on
>   googdocs. i.e. https://
>
> Internet Exploder does the right thing and "currently" nixes an
>   https:// in a non-SSL website which is what everyone is doing here.
>   You can't fix it because the https: root cert relies on a consistent
>   domain name. If my memory serves me right,  there is an RFC that
>   explains embedding SSL documents in a nonSSL website is a no no. So
>   the problem will never get solved for IE cuz they are doing what's
>   right all of a sudden.  heheheheheh. Keep and Share(which I have now
>   switched to)  embeds using JS so it is streaming the content and not a
>   silly

Check this link --> https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/MramTev-03Y

Comment: @rybo111What do you mean with an 'English answer to this'? This is an English answer :/

Comment: Removed sarcasm :) I was asking if it was possible to make the answer more formal/readable, specifically "noone's man land", "Internet Exploder", "cuz", "hehehe", "not a silly"

Answer (score -3):

Please remove Java 6 and all of its recent versions (through the control panel and not through java options) Then install the latest version, this allows you to control the content that you allow Java to access. All the security info is there. However i did not change anything there. We closed IE and then reopened the page and the application prompted us to allow access. This resolved the issue.