# "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" error message (Internet Explorer 11 only)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11, x-frame-options

I have two frontend applications - one is a legacy AngularJS app & another is a Angular 4.x app. The AngularJS application has an iframe that when opens up an dialog which loads content from our Angular 4 app (not ideal I know).

This issue I am having on our local instance this seems fine however when I upload this to our staging servers I am unable to load the iframe in Internet Explorer 11 (it is fine in modern browsers however) and I get the following error

`This content cannot be displayed in a frame
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.`

As I am able to modify the source Angular 4.x app I have added the following meta tag :

`<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">`

But this change doesn't make any difference and I still get the same error message - anyone ideas on how to fix in IE11?

Comment: Are you trying to open HTTPS page from non SSL site? If yes than you can get this kind of error. See here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069805/internet-explorer-error-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame If no, It will be helpful for us, If you provide any sample code. We will try to make a test with it on our end and try to find any possible solution for it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: thanks Deepak i'll give that url a go and post sample code later

Comment: Is your issue solved? If yes, Than try to post the solution here. If no, than try to inform us about the current status for your issue. We will try to provide further suggestions may help you to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - it involved changing the Apache settings directly on the "X-Frame Options" server in question