# Show HTTPS source in Iframe from a local file

Tags: html, iframe, https

we have a local webpage file, very simple, done in notepad. This local file has two iframes in this, the src for each iframe is https. This isn't a hosted page, it is just a local file.

The issue is after a recent update we get the error "publisher doesn't allow content to be displayed in an iframe, open in new window"

Is there a way to allow HTTPS sources within an Iframe on a local webfile? 
I feel it may be something simple I'm missing.

Comment: Given the error message you said was displayed, what makes you think the problem has anything to do with HTTPS?

Comment: What browser(s) have you tested this in?

Comment: You cannot access iFrame source from script from another origin. That is including file:/// - you can start the browser with some lower security settings but that is not recommended

Comment: Quentin, the reason I thought maybe it was an HTTPS issue was because of this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069805/internet-explorer-error-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame

@mplungjan do you know of any other way around that? Browser security settings are managed by Group Policy, and i wouldn't want to lower them regardless. 
These computers are all part of the same domain, the src for the iframe is from one of our applications, it worked before the latest updates

Comment: Don't use an iFrame. Use real servere and ajax the content